# xelatex doesn't work in texstudio

Tags: xetex, texlive, texstudio

I recently installed texlive and texstudio (both last versions) but texstudio  doesn't work when I changed the compiler to xelatex. I get the error :

```
Error: Command crashed: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "texstudio_eB3052".tex
```

I also installed texlive-xetex package, but still didn't work. Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

P.s: I have ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: what happens if you type `xelatex sample2e` on the commandline? check it works there before getting it working via an editor

Comment: yes it works in the terminal.

Comment: OK I t's presumably a path issue the but I can't help as texstudio isn't emacs:)

Comment: Is your file really called `texstudio_eB3052.tex`? And if yes what happens if you try to compile it on the terminal with the quotes mentioned in your error message?

Comment: that was an untitled file. when i type the command: `xelatex sample.tex` in terminal, I get: `This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 4
Babel <3.20> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.cloSegmentation fault (core dumped)
`

Comment: segmentation fault doesn't sound good. And where did you get a texlive 2019/dev from?

Comment: "works in the terminal" and "Segmentation fault" could not be more different!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 2019/dev are the Debian built binaries, but they are only available in Debian/unstable and Debian/testing, so I am surprised to see them in Ubuntu 16.04 ...

I can only assume that the OP did copy binaries from Debian/unstable to Ubuntu 16.04, which is *not a good idea*

Comment: @norbert thank you. I try to install texlive 2018.

Comment: @Bob22 Could you answer my question: what kind of packages did you install on your system? Can you send the output of `dpkg -l texlive-binaries` ? Thanks

Comment: @norbert I just used `sudo apt-get install texlive`. I didn't specify any packages. when I type your command in terminal, I get  `Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name    Version    Architecture   Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-================================================================
ii  texlive-binaries  2018.20180525.47831 amd64  Binaries for TeX Live
`

Comment: Then this is a very different error from the one I was talking about, and I don't know where you get the binaries. Can you send the output of `apt-cache policy texlive-binaries`?

Comment: @norbert I get `texlive-binaries: Installed: 2018.20180525.47831-0york0~16.04
  Candidate: 2018.20180525.47831-0york0~16.04
  Version table:
 *** 2018.20180525.47831-0york0~16.04 500
       500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/texlive/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  2015.20160222.37495-1ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages  500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages 2015.20160222.37495-1 500  500 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: You have installed a much newer version of TeX Live packages into an old version of Ubuntu. I don't know whether there are library incompatibilities or any other problem, but this is AFAIK not a supported setup by Ubuntu.